# Power capabilities of USB 3.0 vs 2.0?

Tags: usb, power, usb-3

I'm currently buying some new USB micro cables for my Samsung Galaxy S5. It supports both USB 2.0 micro and USB 3.0 micro connectors.

Will I see better charging times when using the USB 3.0 cable connected to a wall charger vs. a USB 2.0 cable? I would assume not, but I'm not sure. AFAIK, not too many things draw any more than 2A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Theoretically*, you shouldn't, since wall chargers can supply the same amount of current over a USB 2.0 cable as a USB 3.0 cable.

However, you *might* see a difference in difference in charging times due to the electrical properties of the cables. Because the USB 3 spec calls for a higher maximum current than USB 2 (950 mA vs. 500), it stands to reason that USB 3 cables will be better constructed and thus able to conduct higher amounts of current than run-of-the-mill USB 2 cables. See [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/1yoe2a/lpt_know_why_your_smartphone_is_charging_slowly/) for more information.

Comment: As with most things, it depends - most phone chargers have delivered > 1 A current for a while now (some going > 2 A) over USB 2.0 cables. A properly specced cable is probably fine; the higher current capability of USB 3.0 is mostly dependent on the host, not the cable. But cheaper cables tend to skimp wherever possible, and may be an issue - I have a cheap USB 2.0 extension cable here with a voltage drop of > 1 V over a metre...